# php if statement is not working

Tags: if-statement

$DBRefundExpire  value is coming from the MySQL database and is a timestamp(the default timestamp MySQL provides)

the code will echo a message if the timestamp is more than 60 minutes

```
if(strtotime($DBRefundExpire) > strtotime("-60 minutes")) {
     require('messages/refundExpire.php');
    refundExpiredMsg();
    exit();
} else{
}
```

Comment: "-60 minutes"? Shouldn't be "60 minutes"?

Comment: I don't think timestamps work the way you think they work. Strtotime returns the amount of seconds since 1/1/1970